# Inserting Bytearray into SQL through stored procedure called in C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, arrays

First of all I've tried everything, and can't understand why it won't update my varbinary field properly.

out of 1728 bytes only the last byte in the byte array is saved to the field...

I generate my byte array as follows:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

I have also tried the one below:

```
public static byte[] ParseHex(string hex)
{
    int offset = hex.StartsWith("0x") ? 2 : 0;
    if ((hex.Length % 2) != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length: " + hex.Length);
    }
    byte[] ret = new byte[(hex.Length - offset) / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = (byte)((ParseNybble(hex[offset]) << 4)
                         | ParseNybble(hex[offset + 1]));
        offset += 2;
    }
    return ret;
}

static int ParseNybble(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        return c - '0';
    }
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
    {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    }
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
    {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hex digit: " + c);
}
```

My c# code to save the data is this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_Conn"].ConnectionString))
{
  byte[] to_store = StringToByteArray(inventory);

  //State the Stored Proc and add Values to 'cmd' to pass to the Stored Proc
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("_USP_store", conn);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", TB_A.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@B", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 1728).Value = to_store;

  try
  {
    // Open Connection and execute Stored Proc
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    C2_Wipe_Message.Text = "Storing success";
    C2_Wipe_Message.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255, 0);

  }
  catch
  {
    C2_Wipe_Message.Text = "An error occured..";
    C2_Wipe_Message.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0, 0);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
      //Close connection IF open
      conn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

I've send it as a string, I've send it as plain binary, i've send it as a hexadecimal byte array, etc.

My assumption is to use a while loop in sql, to store it, but that doesn't explain why the last byte is always saved instead of the first byte of the byte array, Please enlighten me cause this is infuriating..

**SQL SP*

```
@A varchar(10),
@B varbinary(1728)

    AS  

UPDATE Invenotry
SET A = @B
WHERE (Name = @A)
```

Comment: Lets see the SQL I expect the problem is there since using a loop in SQL sounds wrong to me.

Comment: not using a loop, but i'll get the sql procedure out

Comment: What is the type of the field `[Invenotry].[A]`?

Comment: It's a varchar(10) field, It holds a name. the app has to fields, for simplicity field A and field B, Field A holds the name, field B holds the human readable output/input of the hexadecimal byte array.

Comment: See answer below based on the Table having fields A and B.  If this is not the case please post the table definition for `Invenotry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sql should be this:

```
UPDATE Invenotry
SET B = @B
WHERE A = @A
```

You can also try the full version of a parameter constructor:

```
SqlParamter param = new SqlParameter("@B", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 1728, ParameterDirection.Input, 
     // we have these parameters but they are ignored for input types
     false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, 
     // the data
     to_store);

cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: testing it now, a side question, which way of converting a hex string to a byte array would you use of the above two ways i discribed? or would you use a different method in total?

Comment: it seems like it did not like the '(' and ')' arround the WHERE clause, however i noticed that my biggest problem was giving the fields a proper name. I have now changed the field names accordingly, and also assigned the proper size to the varbinary field (it was 1726 instead of 1728..)  Though I'm still interested in which conversion to Byte array you'd recommend

Comment: The first one seems simpler however it does not check for the starting `0x` -- do you expect to see the starting `0x`?

Comment: I'm expecting whatever works best with the database field, and has the lowest overhead.

Comment: I think the goal is to have both of them return the same thing -- I expect the internal library will be faster, but the best way to know is to test both.